# Pointer help in BST c++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

My BST has the root called pTree. It is declared by:

```
KnightTree* tree;
```

Now I need to write a function with a new pointer that point to the root (which is "tree" in this case) and never changes event if I use pTree=pTree->pLeftChild; or pTree=pTree->pRightChild;
Before I call the function below I declare:

```
KnightTree* treeroot=tree;
```

Then I call the function:

```
ReadNLR(tree,treeroot);
```

And the function is like this:

```
void ReadNLR(KnightTree*&tree,KnightTree* treeroot)
{
    if(tree !=NULL)
    {
        cout<<tree->key<<" is at the depth of "<<NodeDepth(treeroot,tree)<<endl;
        cout<<treeroot->key<<endl;
        ReadNLR(tree->pLeftChild,treeroot);
        ReadNLR(tree->pRightChild,treeroot);
    }
}
```

My idea is to make a NLR read and every node read will print out its depth. But the problem I have here is that the treeroot just like a copy of tree and they are the same so the depth is always 1 (as distance from the node to the root plus 1). How do I declare the treeroot from the initial tree root that will never changes even if tree change? Thank you, and sorry for my English!

Comment: Please show your `NodeDepth` function. Also it's not clear why `tree` parameter in `ReadNLR` is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, your code looks good, except that there is no reason for the tree argument to be a reference to a pointer. My guess is that there is something wrong with `NodeDepth`. A suggestion would be to just track of the level as you go instead of recalculating it. Your function, which does a [depth-first sweep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search) of the tree, would then look like this:

```
void ReadNLR(KnightTree* tree, int level)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;

    cout << tree->key << " is at the depth of " << level;
    ReadNLR(tree->pLeftChild, level + 1);
    ReadNLR(tree->pRightChild, level + 1);
}
```

You would start the print process by calling `ReadNLR` with `root` and `0` as arguments.

You can also print the tree level by level using a queue - I'll post how shortly if you still need help.

Comment: The NodeDepth is good. I checked it with NodeDepth(tree,(tree->pRightChild)->pRightChild); and it works correctly.

Comment: The fact that it works for a single case is not a guarantee that it will work every time.

Comment: Oh I figured it out... when declaring a make it = new KnightTree(); then assign it =tree and it works :D
Thanks for helping all!